# Обрезание экрана при повороте

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xamarin

Есть `shared` приложение `xamarin.forms`

на пример `ContentPage` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyFin1.Views.Reports
{
    public class Reports_view : ContentPage
    {
        StackLayout Lay = new StackLayout();
        public Reports_view ()
        {
            Lay.Children.Add(
                  new Xamarin.Forms.Label
                  {
                      Text = "Мои Финансы",
                      TextColor = Color.FromRgb(200, 200, 200),
                      HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                      VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                      FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Label)),
                      FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic
                  }
               );
            Button Bar_chart_go = new Button
            {
                Text = "Динамика"
            };
            Button Pie_chart_go = new Button
            {
                Text = "Структура"
            };
            Bar_chart_go.Clicked += Bar_chart_go_Clicked;
            Pie_chart_go.Clicked += Pie_chart_go_Clicked;

            Lay.Children.Add(Bar_chart_go);
            Lay.Children.Add(Pie_chart_go);

            Content = new StackLayout {
                Children = {

                    Lay
                }
            };

        }
        
    }
}
```

на андройд эмуляторе все работает как нужно ( при повороте изображение поворачивается):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда запускаю на wp ( nokia 530) происходит следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом если сначала поворачиваю экран а потом жму назад и возвращаюсь на эту же страницу все выглядит как нужно.
в `MainPage.xaml.cs` стоит
`SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.PortraitOrLandscape;`

можно ли как то это пофиксить?

PS копия вопроса на [EN_SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156694/view-doesnt-resieze-on-rotation)

Comment: Добрый день. Не подскажете, как удалось решить данную проблему? Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, на более свежем XF.